# How to compare the two file paths in shell script

Tags: bash

I am trying to compare my working directory with a correct directory from which the script needs to run.  Here is snippet of shell script

```
CURR_DIR=echo pwd
echo $CURR_DIR
if [ "$CURR_DIR" == "/proj/project_a/scripts_shell" ]; then
    echo "You are running script from correct directory"
fi
```

In this case I ensured that I am in /proj/project_a/scripts_shell (as my present working directory) but for some reason it is not able to detect this in the if statement.  Thus it is not printing the message.

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
if [ "$PWD" = "/proj/project_a/scripts_shell" ]; then
    echo "You are running the script from the correct directory" 
fi
```

The problem is that when you do `CURR_DIR=echo pwd`, the shell calls `pwd` with the environment variable `CURR_DIR` set to `echo`.  When you need to capture the output of a command in a variable, just do `VAR=$(cmd)`.

Comment: This needs double equals, else it will do assignment not evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a notation for saving command result into string in BASH

```
CURR_DIR=$(pwd)
```

or

```
CURR_DIR=`pwd`
```

When you type `CURR_DIR=echo pwd` that's make `CURR_DIR` just a "pwd" string. This is how echo function work. For example execute following line in your shell

```
echo blah blah blah
```

this do nothing with blah command.